# Getting the memory usage details of other jvm

Tags: java, memory, jvm

When I try using `System.getRunTime()` and get the memory details, I am getting the memory details of current JVM. But I need the memory details another java process. I do have a reference to that process (`java.lang.Process`) in my current code. Is it possible to get that process' memory details ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/), it's a nice tool, and try to run only that process using jUnit, so the jvm will show you the process details, or you could name the thread so you can identify what thrad are you looking in the jvm.

Answer (score 0):

- `JMX`
- `jconsole` (uses JMX)
- VisualVM (similar to jconsole)
- somehow using `System.getRuntime().exec("ps -aux/top/whatever")`